# How to solve problem (testing with mutants in java)?

Tags: java, testing

I have to implement algorithm for finding mutants in code. From input file, i have to reading some code for example;

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int s = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    s = s + x[i]; 
  } 
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

I have to create mutants using two rules: replacement of arithmetic operations and
replacement of variables of the same type.
For example: in the code above we have line with code `s=s+x[i];`
The + sign should be replaced by the - sign,
so the first mutant would be;

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int s = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    s = s - x[i]; 
  } 
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Second mutant would be;

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int s = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    s = s / x[i]; 
  } 
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

And so for each sign. Do the same with replacement of variables of the same type.

Mutants must be written to the output file.

I need a solution in Java. Please help?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, then it's not a trivial problem to solve. Correct me if I'm wrong. You need Java code that would read any Java file, find all arithmetic operations in it and would replace them with all other artihmetic operations. So given the input contains N arithmetic operations, you would need to find them all and print out N! permutations of this code. This would mean you would need a fully blown Java code tokenizer/analyzer and build your substitution on top of that. This is not something you can do in few lines of code.

Comment: I know that. I need a whole code, beacuse i can't solve it. I have not idea how to solve the task.P.S. The code is read from a text file.

Comment: Your given example is very simple. But lets say the code contains something line like `String x = "Hello x+y+z" + (10 / 6 * (5*23) + 4); // This is a comment, but just for messing with you x+y+20/53`. This is a totally legit compilable line, but its full of strings and comments which contain "decoy's". Where I'm getting with this, it's not solvable with 1 SO answer. I am assuming this is some kind of assignment from school or somewhere. If it's a reasonable assignment then surely there must be some other constraints. How would you even verify that the input is a legit Java program?

Comment: The program from the input file must be a program in java(testing mutants in java). 
It doesn't have to be exactly what I wrote, it can be different.

Comment: Let put it differently. You are asking something in the level of "How do I build a rocketship? I have no idea how to start, but I'm hoping someone can phrase a simple answer which helps me from zero knowledge to building something that gets me to the moon." Noone can help you with that kind of question. Even if we know exactly how to do it, then it would no be answerable in one SO post. My advice: Try something out, if you run to a concrete problem, show us your code and let's take it from there.

Comment: Have you looked at https://javaparser.org/ ? You can use it to turn your java code into a semantic tree that you can then traverse, transform and generate. It seems perfect for your use case.

Comment: No.I'm not. Thank you very much. 
It is of great help.